# How to Give New Windows 10 User Accounts default Settings Based on a Different Account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

Toward deploying laptops to 10 high school students, my school has created a baseline Windows 10 installation and installed various software that the students will need. (It's volume licensed.) What we've done in the past and intend to do again, is use Macrium Reflect to clone the boot drive to the various laptops. Then, add one user account to each laptop beyond the account used to set them up... One for each student.

This is quick and easy, and covers software installs well. But it doesn't copy any account settings we might have made to the new student accounts. Things like setting a desktop background, showing desktop icons, removing the Windows Store from the taskbar, etc.

Is it possible to tell windows to add a new user to a given machine, using my account to determine/copy all account-level settings? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for any help.